# How do I capture a closure in another closure?

Tags: rust

```
type Time = f32;
type Behaviour<'a,T> = |Time|: 'a -> T;

fn map_one<'a,T,R>(f: |T| -> R
                  ,b: Behaviour<'a,T>)
                  ->  Behaviour<'a,R>{
  |time| -> R {
      f(b(time))
  }
}
```

Err:

```
<anon>:8:9: 8:10 error: captured variable `b` does not outlive the enclosing closure
<anon>:8       f(b(time))
                 ^
<anon>:6:38: 10:2 note: captured variable is valid for the block at 6:37
<anon>:6                   ->  Behaviour<'a,R>{
<anon>:7   |time|  -> R {
<anon>:8       f(b(time))
<anon>:9   }
<anon>:10 }
```

I think the error means that the life time of 'a expires when I try to move `b` into another closure.

How would I express something like this?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967193/rust-function-returning-a-closure-explicit-lifetime-bound-required

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using "boxed" closures. Those closures capture values by reference, so the captured value must live longer than the closure. You're trying to capture `b`, which is a parameter, so its lifetime is the duration of the function call. You cannot do what you want to do with "boxed closures.

Unboxed closures were added to the language to solve issues like this. Here's how `map_one` would be defined:

```
#![feature(overloaded_calls, unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]

type Time = f32;

fn map_one<'a, T, R, F: Fn<(T,), R>, B: Fn<(Time,), T>>(
    f: F, b: B) -> Box<Fn<(Time,), R>+'a> {
  box |&: time| -> R {
      f(b(time))
  }
}
```

`Fn` is a trait with a `call` method that takes `self` by immutable reference (`FnMut` takes `self` by mutable reference and `FnOnce` takes `self` by value). The captured values are *moved* into the closure, rather than referenced.

The input closure parameters are defined with a type parameter that implements the `Fn` trait, which is the only way to pass closures by value. The return value, however, must be boxed, because the concrete result type (which implements `Fn`) is created by the compiler, and we can't name it.

I tried writing a `main` that uses `map_one`, but [I'm getting an internal compiler error](http://is.gd/KHuN0D)... At that point, I can't tell if I made a mistake or if the code is supposed to be valid. (These Rust issues may be related to this error: [#16672](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16672), [#16791](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16791), [#17060](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17060).)

```
fn main() {
    let t = 30f32;
    let fa = |&: a: String| -> uint { a.len() };
    let fb = |&: b: f32| -> String { b.to_string() };
    let m = map_one(fa, fb);
    let r = m.call((t,));
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

---

Note: I couldn't use your `Behaviour` generic type alias to bound `B`.

```
#![feature(overloaded_calls, unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]

type Time = f32;
type Behaviour<T> = Fn<(Time,), T>;

fn map_one<'a, T, R, F: Fn<(T,), R>, B: Behaviour<T>>(
    f: F, b: B) -> Box<Behaviour<R>+'a> {
  box |&: time| -> R {
    f(b(time))
  }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
<anon>:6:41: 6:53 error: `Behaviour` is not a trait
<anon>:6 fn map_one<'a, T, R, F: Fn<(T,), R>, B: Behaviour<T>>(
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:6:41: 6:53 note: `type` aliases cannot be used for traits
<anon>:6 fn map_one<'a, T, R, F: Fn<(T,), R>, B: Behaviour<T>>(
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: With `#[feature(unboxed_closure_sugar)]` you can use `|&:...| -> ...` for `Fn<(...), ...>`. I'd also suggest using `|&mut:...| -> ...` (and `FnMut<(...), ...>`, correspondingly), as it is more general.