# Returning a closure with mutable environment

Tags: closures, rust

I am trying to build a solution to [Graham´s accumulator factory challenge](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Accumulator_factory) which basically requires a function to return a closure that closes over a mutable numeric variable which initial value is received through a parameter. Each call to this closure increments this captured variable by a value that is a parameter to the closure and returns the accumulated value.

After reading the [closures RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0114-closures.md) and some questions about returning unboxed closures (in particular [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967193/rust-function-returning-a-closure-explicit-lifetime-bound-required)). I could finally come up with a solution that compiled, but the result is not what I would expect.

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, unboxed_closure_sugar)]

fn accumulator_factory(n: f64) -> Box<|&mut: f64| -> f64> {
    let mut acc = n;
    box |&mut: i: f64| {
        acc += i; 
        acc
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut acc_cl = accumulator_factory(5f64);
    println!("{}", acc_cl.call_mut((3f64,)));
    println!("{}", acc_cl.call_mut((3f64,)));
}
```

AFAIK this closure captures `acc` by value, the generated struct that acts as the environment is mutable and `acc_cl` should retain the same environment instance between calls.

But the printed result is `6` in both cases, so it seems the modified value is not persisting. And what is more confusing is how this result is computed. On each execution of the closure the initial value of `acc` is `3` even though `n` is `5` when called.

If I modify the generator to this:

```
fn accumulator_factory(n: f64) -> Box<|&mut: f64| -> f64> {
    println!("n {}", n);
    let mut acc = n;
    box |&mut: i: f64| {
        acc += i; 
        acc
    }
}
```

then the execution always return `3` and the initial value of `acc` is always `0` on closure entry.

This difference in semantics looks like a bug. But apart from that, why is the environment reset between calls?

This was run with rustc 0.12.0.

Comment: for another approach you can check this solution: https://github.com/Hoverbear/rust-rosetta/blob/master/src/accumulator_factory.rs . New unboxed closures in rust are sugar for a struct and a trait implementation. This version writes the long "unsugared" version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The capture mode of closures has changed recently. Closures are biased to capture everything by reference because the most common use case for closures is passing them to functions down the call stack, and capturing by reference makes working with the environment more natural.

Sometimes capture by reference is limiting. For example, you can't return such closures from functions because their environment is tied to the call stack. For such closures you need to put the `move` keyword before the closure:

```
fn accumulator_factory(n: f64) -> Box<FnMut(f64) -> f64> {
    println!("n: {}", n);
    let mut acc = n;
    Box::new(move |i: f64| {
        acc += i; 
        acc
    })
}

fn main() {
    let mut acc = accumulator_factory(10.0);
    println!("{}", acc(12.0));
    println!("{}", acc(12.0));
}
```

This program works as intended:

```
n: 10
22
34
```

These two closure kinds are covered by [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/231) RFC.

Comment: Could you call `acc(12.0)` instead of `acc.call_mut((12.0,))` ? The call syntax seems a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @MatthieuM., that's why I said that I don't understand why overloaded calls don't work. They are also feature-gated, but even with this gate lifted the compiler still complains.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Thanks. I wasn´t aware of this change in syntax. I guess things are still changing very fast. Now when I try to change f64 to a generic type I´m running into lifetime issues. But I will write another question for that.

Comment: I edited the code above to make it work on Rust 1.9 nightly. Unboxed closures has been implemented and the syntax was changed as per: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0231-upvar-capture-inference.md